# Specifying a relative path in File in Java

Tags: java, image

I'm uploading images using Spring and Hibernate. I'm saving images on the server as follows.

```
File savedFile = new File("E:/Project/SpringHibernet/MultiplexTicketBooking/web/images/" + itemName);
item.write(savedFile);
```

Where `itemName` is the image file name after parsing the request (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`). I however need to mention the *relative path* in the constructor of `File`. Something like the one shown below.

```
File savedFile = new File("MultiplexTicketBooking/web/images/" + itemName);
item.write(savedFile);
```

But it doesn't work throwing the `FileNotFoundException`. Is there a way to specify a relative path with `File` in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the server should offer functionality as might be seen in the methods [`getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29) or [`getRealPath(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).  It would be common to build paths based on those types of server related and reproducible paths.  Do *not* use something like `user.dir` which makes almost no sense in a server.

### Update

```
ServletContext sc=request.getSession().getServletContext(); 
File savedFile = new File(sc.getRealPath("images")+"\\" + itemName);
```

Rather than use `"\\"` I'd tend to replace that with the following which will cause the correct file separator to be used for each platform.  Retain cross-platform compatibility for when the client decides to swap the MS/ISS based server out for a Linux/Tomcat stack.  ;)

```
File savedFile = new File(sc.getRealPath("images"), itemName); //note the ','
```

See [`File(String,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for details.

Comment: I did something like this `ServletContext sc=request.getSession().getServletContext();` `File savedFile = new File(sc.getRealPath("images")+"\\" + itemName);` and it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Suppose sir my path is `\\ADMIN\keyur\Workspace\B2B Solution\WebContent\product_images` that is on network server, what I ll have to use ?

Answer (score 3):

Try printing the working directory from your program.

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Gets you that directory. Then check if the directories `MultiplexTicketBooking/web/images/` exist in that directory.

Can't count the number of times I've been mistaken about my current dir and spent some time looking for a file I wrote to...

Answer (score 2):

You could get the path of your project using the following -

```
File file = new File("");
System.out.println("" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

So you could have a `constants` or a `properties` file where you could define your path which is `MultiplexTicketBooking/web/images/` after the relative path.

You could append your path with the path you get from `file.getAbsolutePath()` and that will be the real path of the file. - `file.getAbsolutePath() + MultiplexTicketBooking/web/images/`.

Make sure the folders after the Project path i.e. `MultiplexTicketBooking/web/images/` exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path both absolute and relative with `File`. The `FileNotFoundException` can be thrown because the folder might be there. Try using the `mkdirs()` method first in to create the folder structure you need in order to save your file where you're trying to save it.